# How do I reaach a nested property in a JSON file with AngularJS in front end

Tags: angularjs, json, nested

I am using angularJS to show in frontend the data I have got from the server like this:

```
<h1>Name: {{vm.contact.firstName}} </h1>
<h2>Company : {{vm.contact.organizationName }} /h2>
```

My problem is that I have got the information in a JSOn file from the server with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": "dcbb9daf-b40f-4c59-84a4-804ebb34159c",
    "title": "Mr.",
    "jobTitle": "Recruiting Manager",
    "firstName": "pablo",
    "lastName": "Ordoñez",
    "organizationId": "2d6a6bb2-0c09-48f0-9f97-7463fada1e01",
    "standard": {
              "id": "2d6a6bb2-0c09-48f0-9f97-7463fada1e01",
               "dateCreated": "2015-12-09T02:46:40",
               "dateUpdated": "2016-07-28T19:30:14",
               "hidden": false,
               "organizationName": "Madrider",
                "contacts": []
               }
  }
]
```

The data under "standard" belongs to the organization which ID is shown as organizationID.

How do I get into the second level?

Eventually I will get a third level, as you see the last itelm is an empty array contacts[] holding the colleagues in that company.

How do I reach successive nested levels?

**EDIT:**

My view.Html looks like:

```
<div class="legend">{{ vm.contact.standard.organizationName}} - {{vm.contact.length}} contacts</div>

<h1>Name: {{vm.contact.firstName}} </h1>
<h2>Company : {{  vm.contact.standard.organizationName }} /h2>
```

**The result in browser looks like:**
Notice it recognize the contact.length = 3 contacts

[image]

Comment: Just use vm.contact.standar.dateCreated, and in you need to go deeper just use property names

Comment: No, that method vm.contact.standad.organizationName did not work

Comment: Can you provide an error? Without an error, it's impossible to guess what the problem is.  Also, perhaps you mis-typed the property names.  In your comment, you typed "standad" instead of "standard".

Comment: There is not error at all. It just do not show any thing.
The front end looks like this: 
{{ vm.contact.standard.organizationName}}

Comment: If it displays your binding instead of evaluating it, it's that you didn't load your app, did you set ng-app, Or even better can you provide a snippet to see whats happening?

Comment: I have added the snipped plus an screenshot

Comment: contact is an array you should use vm.contact[0]